# Context menu on nested child element also shows parent context menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, contextmenu, jquery-ui-contextmenu

I have multiple DOM elements with context menus. When one element is a child of the other and I invoke the context menu of the inner child, I also see the context menu from the parent. This is implemented with the [jquery-ui.contextmenu](https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu) plugin.

Is there a way to configure the plugin to prevent the parent's menu from being shown or am I going to have to handle all the click events manually and filter them so I show only the menu I want?

Following is my code:

HTML:

```
    <!-- Add a child which will have a context menu -->
    <div class="outer-child" id="outer-child">
        Outer Child

        <!-- inner child with its own context menu -->
        <div class="inner-child" id="inner-child">
            Inner Child
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: green;
}
.inner-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: yellow;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// create context menu on outer child
$("#outer-child").contextmenu({
    menu: [
        {title: "This is the Outer Menu", cmd: "outer-menu"}
        ],
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert("select " + ui.cmd + " on " + ui.target.text());
    }
});


// create context menu on inner child
$('#inner-child').contextmenu({
    menu: [
        {title: "Inner Menu", cmd: "inner-menu"}
        ],
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert("select " + ui.cmd + " on " + ui.target.text());
    }
});
```

You can find a jsfiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nigelt/u0ynqdh5/2/). (*Right-click the inner box and see both context menus*)

Answer (score 6):

You can fix this issue by calling `event.stopPropagation()` method in the `beforeOpen` event of child element.

```js
// create context menu on outer child
$("#outer-child").contextmenu({
  menu: [{
    title: "This is the Outer Menu",
    cmd: "outer-menu"
  }],
  select: function(event, ui) {
    alert("select " + ui.cmd + " on " + ui.target.text());
  },

});


// create context menu on inner child
$('#inner-child').contextmenu({
  beforeOpen: function(event, ui) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  },
  menu: [{
    title: "Inner Menu",
    cmd: "inner-menu"
  }],
  select: function(event, ui) {
    alert("select " + ui.cmd + " on " + ui.target.text());
  }
});
```

```css
.outer-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: green;
}
.inner-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://wwwendt.de/tech/demo/jquery-contextmenu/jquery.ui-contextmenu.js"></script>
<!-- Create an area to contain our editable components -->
<div class="container" id="container">
  <!-- Add a child which will have a context menu -->
  <div class="outer-child" id="outer-child">Outer Child
    <!-- inner child with its own context menu -->
    <div class="inner-child" id="inner-child">Inner Child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```