# jQuery Ui Context menu dereference the id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-contextmenu

How can I retreive the ids of contexts menu just like in https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu/blob/master/README.md, but with additionally provided IDs

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu1" class="hasmenu">AAA</div>
    <div id="menu2" class="hasmenu">AAA</div>
</div>
```

in the select method?

```
$("#container").contextmenu({
    delegate: ".hasmenu",
    menu: [
    {title: "Copy", cmd: "copy", uiIcon: "ui-icon-copy"}
    ],
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert("select " + ui.target.id); // ui.target.id fails!!!
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`ui.target` is a jQuery element, not a plain javascript `HTMLElement`. You can get at *that* with the `[0]` suffix (`$(ui.target)[0].id`) or, more readably, just use [the jQuery attribute accessor function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
ui.target.attr("id")
```

[Here's a link to a fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/blgt/eazomero/) and a stack snippet below

```js
$("#container").contextmenu({
    delegate: ".hasmenu",
    menu: [
    {title: "Copy", cmd: "copy", uiIcon: "ui-icon-copy"}
    ],
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert("select " + ui.target.attr("id"));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui-contextmenu/1.8.0/jquery.ui-contextmenu.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu1" class="hasmenu">AAA</div>
    <div id="menu2" class="hasmenu">AAA</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just beaten me to it... :)

Comment: @TJ completely offtopic: is there a FAQ page about the stack snippets? I tried to add one here, but can't seem to figure it out, or find a tutorial

Comment: I'm only aware of [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) Maybe I can help you if you're having a particular issue because this contextmenu thingy is [working for me in snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26575857/2333214)...

Comment: Thanks, I had completely missed the "add libraries" button (which just inserted a `<source>`..)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
$(ui.target).closest('div').attr('id');
```